# Is there a theoretical upper limit for the Yukawa-like coupling constant in a theory with a cut-off scale?

Tags: standard-model

In the fermion mass terms in the Standard Model,

$y_x\bar{L}H d_x$ or $y_x\bar{L}\tilde{H} u_x$ where $y_x$ are the Yukawa couplings,

we have $y_x<<1$ except for the case of the top quark. For the top quark, $y_t \sim 1$. As I understand, this is around the maximum value the coupling constant can have because of the conditions imposed by perturbativity and unitarity. On the other hand, if I write a non-renormalizable mass term,

$y'_x\frac{\Phi}{\Lambda}\bar{L}H d_x$ where $y'_x$ is the Yukawa-like coupling, $\Phi$ is a hypothetical gauge singlet scalar field, $\Lambda$ is the cut-off scale (for example the GUT scale),

does such a maximum limit exist for $y'_x$? Here, the Standard Model Yukawa coupling is obtained as $y_x = y'_x \frac{\langle\Phi\rangle}{\Lambda}$ where $\langle\Phi\rangle$ is the Vacuum expectation value of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yukawa couplings are not constrained theoretically.

That said, from 'tHooft's technical naturalness point of view, all the dimensionless Yukawa couplings
$$
y_x
$$
should be of order 1.

Hence, only top quark's $y_t$ is natural, while the rest $y_x$ are not natural. There should be an insofar unknown symmetry (and spontaneous symmetry breaking thereof) protecting the smallness of non-top $y_x$.

So if your gauge singlet scalar $\Phi$ is endowed with some global symmetry, then non-top $y_x$ are more exciting, since you hit the jackpot of explaining the Fermion mass hierarchies.

Mind you that the Higgs mass naturalness/hierarchy is a different beast.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for letting me know about the 'tHooft's naturalness.

Comment: I am still confused about the top Yukawa coupling being close to 1. I thought that the Yukawa coupling being greater than 1 causes some problems in the Standard Model. If the top Yukawa were (hypothetically)  ~10 and the top mass were ~1760 GeV, will it still be okay theoretically?

Yes, I am introducing $\Phi$ to explain the Fermion mass hierarchies through Froggatt-Nielsen mechanism.

Comment: Larger top Yukawa or top mass would have an impact on the Higgs mass quantum corrections, which has a bearing on the Higgs hierarchy problem. However, Froggatt-Nielsen are concerned with the relative ratios between quarks/leptons masses, thus absolute value of top may not be a major concern. On the other hand, if Higgs is composite and made of top-antitop condensation, then Higgs mass and top mass are closely related, rendering top being 1760 GeV impossible.